# SAS : PROC IMPORT CSV - Encoding - specific caractere in columns names

Tags: csv, import, sas

How can we import a csv file with specific caractere in colnames ? When I open this CSV with Visual Code, 2 colnames contain this caractere �. Is there a way to import my file with proc import (not a datastep) ?

***SAS version 9.04***

I try this :

```
filename test2  "my_file.csv" encoding="utf-8" ;


proc import datafile= test2
out=my_df
dbms=dlm
replace;
delimiter=";";
getnames=yes;
GUESSINGROWS=MAX;
run;
```

Raise an error :

```
ERROR: Invalid string.
ERROR: Invalid string.
ERROR: Invalid string.
Nombre de noms trouvé inférieur au nombre de variables trouvé. 
Le nom  n'est pas un nom SAS correct.
Problèmes détectés dans les noms fournis. Consultez le Journal.
....
ERROR: Invalid string.
FATAL: Unrecoverable I/O error detected in the execution of the DATA step program.  Aborted during 
the EXECUTION phase.
```

Comment: What version of SAS are you using? I am on 9.4M7 and it gives me this warning but imports successfully: `WARNING: A character that could not be transcoded has been replaced in record 0.` Type `%put &sysvlong.` and post the results.

Comment: Given the language differences I suspect that encoding may be an issue. What is your file encoding and your SAS encoding default set to?

Comment: Also, a data step is easy enough - the log should include the code for the data step above the issues you've included below - not sure why you're not considering it an option.

Comment: Result of %put &sysvlong. 9.04.01M3P062415

Comment: I suppose encoding file is utf-8 because � correspond to é.
Default sas encoding is WLatin1.

Comment: I'd rather a proc import because I have lot of columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the trick **encoding="Windows-1250"**:

```
filename test2 "my_file.csv" encoding="Windows-1250" ;


proc import datafile= test2
   out=my_df
   dbms=dlm
   replace;
   delimiter=";";
   getnames=yes;
   GUESSINGROWS=MAX;
run;
```

**Tips :** to choose right encoding :

File > Import data > Choose your file ...  > In open window click on "Codage ..." > In my case Codage "Europe de l'Ouest (Windows) (Page de code 1252) Import correctly "é" : check below in overview.

**To have right syntax of encoding "1250" refers to :**  https://support.sas.com/documentation/onlinedoc/dfdmstudio/2.6/dmpdmsug/Content/dfU_Encodings.html